# Размер папки больше объема жесткого диска, Win10

Tags: windows-10, файловая-система

Появилась такая проблема - ёмкость жесткого диска - 217 Гб. На диске есть папка Phone с другими папками, содержащими фотографии. Некоторые из подпапок Phone имеют размер в несколько терабайт. На приведённом ниже скриншоте виден размер всех папок (папки, имеющие адекватный содержимому размер подсвечены розовым).

*Скриншот подпапок Phone*

[image: картинка 1]

Также прикладываю скриншот свойств проблемной папки.

[image: картинка 2]

Есть подозрения на то, что к такому странному поведению причастно то, что в подпапках находится большое количество файлов (по ~600 фоток). Ни один графический редактор, разумеется, не открывает фото в тех папках, в которых размер файлов искажён. При попытке копирования файла из проблемной подпапки (неважно, имеет ли файл нормальный размер или 9 гб) - выдаётся ошибка "Не удаётся записать, снимите защиту от записи!". Если бы информация не была важна,
 то решение было бы элементарным - отформатировать диск, но делать этого крайне не хотелось бы.

Содержимое подпапки

[image: картинка 3]

Есть ли возможность починить папку, не потеряв данные?

Comment: Хм. А вы уверены, что диск или файловая система не повреждены?

Comment: Проверял командой chkdsk, ошибок найдено не было. Больше проблема никак себя не проявляет, в остальном диск работает нормально. Есть ещё способы проверить файловую систему на повреждения?

Comment: А если написать простую программу, которая открывает файл, читает его поблочно и копирует на другой диск? Кстати, я бы не рекомендовал записывать что-то на диск D до решения проблемы. т. к. если файловая система и правда повреждена, можно потерять данные.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, подумаю над этим