# Windows 10: фото и видео стали весить по 8Гб

Tags: windows-10

На рабочем столе папка с фото и видео преобразовалась:
-Размер всей папки - 4,27Тб, хотя локальный диск всего 28,6Гб. Да и сам хард 240Гб.
-Размер каждого фото стал ровно 7,66Гб.
-Размер каждого видео стал от 7,71Гб до 8,12Гб.
-Размер на диске каждого фото и видео стал ровно 4Кб.
-Файлы не читаются.
-Файлы копировать можно. Но размер и размер на диске становятся тоже 7,66Гб.

Остальные фото на рабочем столе, даже новые, не меняются.
Проверял на вирусы - ничего.
Жесткий проверил через chkdsk - ничего.
Нашел только такое [Размер папки больше объема жесткого диска, Win10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653037) но там у файлов не страдал размер на диске.

Скажите, есть возможность восстановить или дело гиблое?

Comment: Для начала прогнать проверку диска наверное?

Comment: Да, диск проверил. Ничего битого нет. Программы для восстановления файлов тоже не помогли.